# XML serialization. End of file occurred

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I try to serialize list of 15 objects this way:

```
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>));
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

                // Serialize
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, allKnownWorkers);

                memStream.Position = 0;

                data = memStream.GetBuffer();
                Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");


                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); // NetworkStream
```

Deserialization looks like:

```
            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>));
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

            memStream.Write(data, 0, bytes);
            memStream.Position = 0;

            // Deserialize
            workers.AddRange((List<Employee>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memStream));
```

I get an exception in last line of deserialization: `Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: ...` When I send list with only few objects it works correctly. I suppose there is a problem with stream buffer length. How can I fix it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating your stream-based network connection as if it were message based. But it's not. So you can't count on a single read from the stream returning all of the data for a single object, or even a single transmission.

Instead, you need to design into your protocol a way to know when you've read all the data for a unit of processing (whatever that happens to be in the given context...here that seems to be an XML document).

There are lots of ways to accomplish this. I would say the two most straightforward would be to either transmit a byte count first, before the XML data, so that the receiver knows how many bytes to read before the try to read the XML, or to simply build the XML parsing into the stream reading.

On that latter point, you might try just handing the network stream to your XmlSerializer. I don't recall off the top of my head how well it will handle this, but it could work as long as the XmlSerializer stops reading once it's got a complete XML document, instead of trying to read all the way to the end of the stream. But even if XmlSerializer doesn't just give it to you for free, it should not be too hard to detect the opening tag for the XML document's root element and then just keep reading data until you read the closing tag.